# how to get Selenium fully working in google Colab

Tags: python, selenium, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use selenium in google colab but the script returns nothing. When I run that same script on my local machine it works...

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
import re
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

link= 'http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf'
driver.get(link)
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
# sleep(10)
html_source = driver.page_source
soup_source=bs(html_source,'html.parser')
```

I've tried additional things like pausing the script but it does not work. If someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: How are you initializing the `driver` object? Which browser are you using? Which version of that browser's web driver are you using? What is the error message?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi, sorry about that I just updated the question

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: i'm not getting any error message, it returns nothing so does not work. When I run in on my local computer it returns the content of the page

Comment: I was able to point to other web pages and read them using your code through line where you assign the driver = webdriver.Chrome.   There is something about the pdf you are trying to read -- not sure why you would use this read a pdf.  Your code for installing on a Colab notebook is actually very helpful.